# How many reflexive relations on $P(A)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

There exist a set $A = \{1,2,3\}$.
How many reflexive relations are there on $P(A)$?
I don't even know how to begin (beside writting down the members of $P(A)$).
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be any finite set. Then a relation is a subset of $X \times X$ and it is reflexive if it contains $\Delta_X = \{(x,x) \:|\: x \in X\}$. Thus we are looking for the number of subsets of $X \times X$ containing $\Delta_X$ and this is the same as looking for the number of subsets of $(X \times X) - \Delta_X$. This set has $|X|^2 - |X|$ elements and so it has $2^{|X|^2 - |X|}$ subsets. Now just plug in $X = P(A)$.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your answer, but I didn't understand why "this is the same as looking for the number of subsets of (X×X)−ΔX ?? Beside this part I understood everything..

Comment: If $A$ is a set and $B \subseteq A$ is a subset, then there is a bijection between the set of subsets of $A - B$ and the set of subsets of $A$ containing $B$ by mapping a subset $C \subseteq A - B$ to $C \cup B$. The inverse is given by mapping $D \subseteq A$ (with $B \subseteq D$) to $D - B \subseteq A - B$.

Comment: Reflexivity means $\forall x\in S, xRx$, so $\forall x\in R, (x,x)$ must be included in $R$. There are $X\times X$ pairs in total, and $X$ pairs like $(x,x)$ are fixed, so there are $X\times X-X$ pairs which you can either add or drop them from $R$.